# Why does the Meta off-topic close reason refer to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, off-topic

Closing a programming question as off-topic here on Meta generates this message:

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>   "Programming questions are off-topic on Meta Stack Overflow. Please refer to **[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)** on Stack Overflow.

Why does the link of *how to ask* refer to *Stack Overflow* and not to a *Meta how to ask* page?

If a user follows that link (s)he might be confused since the description found there might fit his/her question.

Comment: Well, the link for how to ask questions on meta is not very relevant if they don't have a question that belongs on meta anyway.

Answer (score 9):

People who are so confused that they end up posting programming questions here on Meta tend to come from, on the whole, the same group of people who should pay extra attention to the Stack Overflow "How to Ask" guidance before reposting their question there.

The intent is to point them to the right place while simultaneously encouraging them to make sure their question is in the best shape possible.

That said, the wording could be a little clearer about this. Perhaps instead of

> Please refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on Stack Overflow.

the following might be more appropriate:

> Please consider [asking your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on Stack Overflow instead.

Comment: +1 for *Please consider asking your question on Stack Overflow instead.*

Comment: To be fair, usually when people ask programming questions here they could do with reading SO's How To Ask before posting them there.